# Understanding Order object in c

Tags: c

How do i Create and return an Order object which has been pre-filled with the provided parameters :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
int day, month, year;
} Date;

typedef struct {
char customer_name[1000]; //Name of the customer placing the order
int order_number; //The order number
Date order_date; //The date on which the order was placed
float total_price;
} Order;

/* print_order(the_order)
Given an Order object, print the order's details in the same format
described in the section above.
*/
void print_order(Order the_order){
printf("Order %d: Placed by %s on %d/%d/%d (price: %0.2f)\n", the_order.order_number, 
the_order.customer_name, the_order.order_date.month, the_order.order_date.day, 
the_order.order_date.year, the_order.total_price);
}

/* create_order(order_number, year, month, day, customer_name, price)
Create and return an Order object which has been pre-filled with the
provided parameters.
*/
 Order create_order( int order_number, int year, int month, int day, char 
customer_name[], float price ){
/* Your code here */
}

int main(){

Order orderA = create_order(111, 2021, 11, 25, "Rebecca Raspberry", 6.10);
Order orderB = create_order(116, 2021, 161, 29, "Fiona Framboise", 17.0);

//Print each order
print_order(orderA);
print_order(orderB);

//Now reassign orderB to have different details (notice that an initializer could not be 
used here)
orderB = create_order(225, 2017, 10, 6, "Neal Naranja", 18.7);
//Print the new order
print_order(orderB);

return 0;
}
```

Im not sure what `Order create_order( int order_number, int year, int month, int day, char  customer_name[], float price ){` is, can anyone please explain what it is?

Like i lets say an output of

```
Order 111: Placed by Rebecca Raspberry on 11/25/2021 (price: $6.10)
Order 116: Placed by Fiona Framboise on 11/29/2021 (price: $17.00)
Order 225: Placed by Neal Naranja on 10/6/2017 (price: $18.70)
```

How do i do this using it? could anyone show me an example of this?

Comment: That function creates an `Order` type (which is a struct) with using types like  `int order_number, int year, int month, int day, char  customer_name[], float price`

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed C99 then this is a possibility:

```c
Order create_order( int order_number, int year, int month, int day, char 
customer_name[], float price ) {
    Order order = {
        .order_number = order_number,
        .total_price = price,
        .price = { .day = day, .year = year, .month = month }
    };
    strcpy(order.customer_name, customer_name);
    return order;

}
```